# Azure Backup and how retention policies are executed

Tags: azure

I had couple of question regarding azure backup

1. what is Incremental Backup in Azure. --> Is it merge all the incremental backups together with full backup?
2. And as per retention policies:  For example, Daily retention policy - Backups are taken daily(Let's say today) at specific times(let's say at 4:00 PM)stored for specific days(let's say for 7 days). So after 7 days (i.e. on the 8th day)backup taken today at 4 PM will be deleted? and how we will be able to get data of that back up during recovery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is Incremental Backup in Azure. --> Is it merge all the
>   incremental backups together with full backup?

Do you mean full backup + one day incremental backup can restore it? If I understand it correctly, the answer is no, we should keep all the incremental backups and full backup.

Difference between Full backup and incremental backup, please refer to this image:
[image]

> And as per retention policies: For example, Daily retention policy -
>   Backups are taken daily(Let's say today) at specific times(let's say
>   at 4:00 PM)stored for specific days(let's say for 7 days). So after 7
>   days (i.e. on the 8th day)backup taken today at 4 PM will be deleted?
>   and how we will be able to get data of that back up during recovery?

Retention policies can only be applied on backup poins. Each recovery point behaves like a full point.

So, we will be able recovery your data with newest backup points.

**Update:**

About retention policy, if we select daily retention policy, backups taken daily are stored for seven days. Also Azure will create two recover points one day if we use Daily retention policy.
[image]

More information about retention policy, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-backup-cloud-as-tape#example--putting-both-together).

Comment: Just one dought what if let say backup of File "A" was taken on day 1(Retention period 7 days) and it was removed from local storage on the 6th day(NO Changes Made to file "A" over this period). Will file A will be available to restore on the 9th day?

Comment: @Vshah Yes, we can restore to day 1 on 9th day. Let's say,we select weekly (7 days)retention policy, Azure will keep those for four weeks. I will update my answer, please check it few mins later:)

Comment: Ye I was mentioning Retention period 7 days in context to the "Daily Retention Policy: Backup taken daily are stored for seven days" mentioned in the updated answer. So my understanding was If the backup of file A was taken on day 1 and there was no change made to file until day 6 when it was removed from the local storage. **As due to no change to file A no backup for the same was taken during six days.** on the 9th day in the newest recovery point of the 9th day, I won't be able to find file A. For file "A" I will need to look in early recovery point of 2nd to 6th day.

Comment: @Vshah "For file "A" I will need to look in early recovery point of 2nd to 6th day."  You are right :)

Comment: @Jeson Ye So if file "A" was never deleted or changed on local storage it will appear in every newest recovery point? and if as mentioned in previous comment file "A" was removed on the 6th day, if we look for file "A" on the 15th or any other day when recovery point of day 1 to 6th have been deleted then no record of the file "A" will be there. Am I getting this correct?

Comment: @Vshah you are right, do some change on file A on local storage, it will appear in every newest recovery point. if you want to find the file A, we need use old recovery point.

Comment: @Vshah Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Your provided information was useful and cleared my concepts on how incremental backup works and retention policies are executed. Thank You.